# How to get the thieves guild skill line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I keep finding small blue boxes around the world, but i cannot open them because i do not have the thieves guild skill line.

Where or how can you obtain this skill line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those boxes are **Thieves Troves** and to open them you simply have to be a member of the **Thieves Guild**, which can be accomplished by buying the DLC pack of the same name (or the whole **Guilds and Glory** collection) and then joining the guild by completing the very first quest associated with that content (*Partners in Crime*).

Comment: So its DLC content?

Comment: @Vahx Yes, that's part of the *Thieves Guild* DLC.

Comment: @Vahx If you have subscription, you have access to all DLC's.